# JavaScript - Make a variable change every second

Tags: javascript

Ok, so this is my code:

```
    name: function(gameServer, split) {
    // Validation checks
    var id = parseInt(split[1]);
    if (isNaN(id)) {
        console.log("[Console] Please specify a valid player ID!");
        return;
    }

    var name = split.slice(2, split.length).join(' ');
    if (typeof name == 'undefined') {
        console.log("[Console] Please type a valid name");
        return;
    }
    var premium = "";
    if (name.substr(0, 1) == "<") {
        // Premium Skin
        var n = name.indexOf(">");
        if (n != -1) {

            premium = '%' + name.substr(1, n - 1);
            for (var i in gameServer.skinshortcut) {
                if (!gameServer.skinshortcut[i] || !gameServer.skin[i]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (name.substr(1, n - 1) == gameServer.skinshortcut[i]) {
                    premium = gameServer.skin[i];
                    break;
                }

            }
            name = name.substr(n + 1);

        }
    } else if (name.substr(0, 1) == "[") {
        // Premium Skin
        var n = name.indexOf("]");
        if (n != -1) {

            premium = ':http://' + name.substr(1, n - 1);
            name = name.substr(n + 1);
        }
    }
```

and i want to change premium to something like `<kraken>` and `<spy>` every second, so that then it changes `gameServer.skinshortcut` to `%kraken` and then 1 second later it changes that to `%spy`... and cycles, How do I do this?

Comment: `setInterval(function(){/*do stuff here*/}, 1000);`

Comment: I agree with PHPglue and only add that maybe you want to make a routine that has each of the variables you want to change in it in either a switch statement or an IF block or build a command that is passed in to the setInterval() function.

Comment: `gameServer.skinshortcut` is an array. What does it mean to change it to `?kraken` or `?spy`?

Comment: Barmar - It sets gameServer.skin to %kraken or %spy so it can then be used by the GameServer functions to use that text to put an image on a cell in a game (agar.io)

Answer (score 1):

Use [setInterval(function, delay in ms)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: While this is the correct answer, you should really give a small, working example to demonstrate how it's used. Applying it and completely solving their problem isn't necessary, but a quick demonstration is always good, especially for things like setInterval that need to be actively turned off.

Comment: Well, what should I use it on? Could you please send me the code of the edited version?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Var pre_stat=0;
function tgl_pre()
if (pre_stat=0)
{
pre_stat=1;
//change variable to `kraken`;
}
else
{
pre_stat=0;
//change variable to 'spy';
}
setInterval("tgl_pre()", 1000);
```

end

Comment: The comment lines refer to whatever code you need to add for the change to occur. Sometimes it takes a little experimenting as to where the safest place to change the variables are.  Chances are they might need to be functions themselves. This will run outside of your code and simply make 1 second interval calls to change something safe. I did not want to muck around with the insides of your otherwise functioning code. I leave that up to you.

Comment: Ok, now what I want to do is I want to trigger the name skin, and in my console I can do "name 1 <spy>" and it triggers the name function. I want to see if I can somehow trigger the name function to do that in the script, but loop between "name 1 <kraken>" and "name 1 <spy>"

Comment: Be sure you have this code wrapped in opening and closing JavaScript tags. The 'setInterval' timer needs to be inside the closing tag, but outside the closing brace. This is just a timing thread. You can use it to call an inside function directly if that works best, as long as it knows how to toggle between 2 states 'kraken' and 'spy'.

Comment: Well, I dont understand the closing brace and closing tag part

Comment: Just for testing purposes you can add 'document.write('pre_stat');, or other variables besides 'pre_stat' to see if they are changing state every second. Quite often I have to add temporary 'probes' to complex programs to find the 'hang-up', the point at which the code stops functioning.